# TypeError: sockets.forEach is not a function

Tags: android, node.js, sockets

i am trying to create a simple personal chat with node js and android.the following code works fine

```
socket.on('message' , function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
   io.emit('message' , {message : msg});
})
```

when a message is receive from a client, the server send it to all other client connected to the server. but the problem is that the sender receive his own message as well. to overcome this issue i am using the following code

```
 socket.on('message' , function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    //io.emit('message' , {message : msg});
   var sockets = io.sockets.sockets;
    sockets.forEach(function (sock) {
        if(sock.id != socket.id){
            sock.emit('message' , {message:msg})
        }
    })
})
```

but the code above produces an error

> TypeError: sockets.forEach is not a function

can anyone help me with this and save my day? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As for Socket.io v1.4.5, it should be:

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets);
```

This returns an array containing id's of sockets connected and you can apply forEach on it.

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).forEach(function(id) {
    console.log("ID:",id)  // socketId
});
```

To send a message to a particular socket, you can use:

```
io.to(socketId).emit()
```

Comment: thank you for response. and it works. but the callback function just gives the id of the socket. i want the socket itself to send message to

Comment: I edited the answer. You can use `io.to(id).emit()` to send message to a particular socket.

Comment: you are really good. worked perfect man. do you know any good node socket io source ?

Comment: @MostafaHakimi Upvote and mark it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

I input `npm install socket.io@1.3.5 --save` in commandline

Comment: Thanks for solving the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the version. Go to package.json and change like this:

```
..
.
..
..
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.5"
  },
```